# Could not find 'MathJax.js' in Local Directory

Tags: r, plotly, mathjax

I am trying to load Mathjax locally as recommended in this link from [plotly-r](https://plotly-r.com/mathjax.html). I think I have loaded the repo for version 3 of MathJax and not version 2 following the instructions on the previous link and [this one](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html) (i.e. there is no `MathJax.js` file in the `es5` directory). So, should I load version 2 or which of the `*.js` files in the `es5` directory will work with plotly-r?